# what's difference between page.locator("xx",has=Locator) and page.locator("xx").filter(has=Locator) in Playwright

Tags: python, playwright

HTML like:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <h3>Product 1</h3>
    <button class="button">Add to cart</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3>Product 2</h3>
    <button class="button">Add to cart</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

when i wanna locating the first `<li>`, i can write like:

```
#the first solution:
page.locator("li",has=page.get_by_text("Product 1"))

#the second solution:
page.locator("li").filter(has=page.get_by_text("Product 1"))
```

what's any detailed difference between these two solutions?

Answer (score 0):

They both return the same element. However, with the second solution you can always sprinkle a few assertions before filtering down within that element.

```
// get element
el = page.locator('li')
// check it is visible before searching within
expect(el).toBeVisible()
// now we get product 1
product1 = el.filter(has=page.get_by_text("Product 1")
```

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario, those two lines of code will give you the exact same result. The reason for having the two approaches is that they *can* be used for different purposes.

The `has` option within the `locator` method only seems to be available within that method, but otherwise is noted to be similar to filter.

The `filter` method is more robust. You can use it on any locator created using any method, like `get_by_role`. It also allows you to perform the filter separately/later, on any locator, so you can just filter when it’s needed for a specific scenario or whenever it makes sense. Another benefit is that you can chain as many as you want, for instance to see if it has two specific elements inside it.

Basically, `has` within `locator` is just a more limited or specific use case of `filter`, while `filter` can do the same functionality plus more.

Since you’re using `locator`, with one filter, and don’t need the general locator to use or filter again to get a different element, the `has` within `locator` option works for you equally with `filter`.